# How to transform this correctly?

Tags: would-rather, transformation

The question is:

> Attir prefers hiking in the hills to relaxing on a beach.

We need to use rather.
However, there are options and I need to choose the most appropriate one.
The options are:

> (a)- Attir would rather prefer hiking in the hills to relaxing on a
> beach.
>
> (b)-Attir would rather hike in the hills than relax on a beach.
>
> (c)-Attir does not prefer hiking in hills rather than relaxing on a
> beach.
>
> (d)-Attir rather not hike in hills than to relax on a beach.

I guess (a) and (b) are both right. Which one will be the most appropriate?
Is (a) right when it doesn't use than? Is it mandatory to use than with rather when we have two alternatives or we can use another word like "to" in (a)?

Comment: (b) is the correct answer. (a) is wrong because _would rather_ and _prefers_ are synonyms, so you don't need both.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct answer here is

(b)-Attir would rather hike in the hills than relax on a beach.

In the sentence (a) 'would rather' and 'prefer' is a like a repetition, as 'would rather' has the meaning of what one prefers.

The usage of 'to' with 'rather' doesn't sound right.

Alternately you could construct a sentence like:

Attir prefers hiking in the hills to relaxing on a beach.

This sentence may not be helpful in this context, as you need to transform the sentence using 'rather'.